# Detect 24 vs 12 hour clock on a users computer

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I am looking for a better way of detecting if the current PC is using a 24 hour clock or a 12 hour clock

[DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern(v=vs.95).aspx) states that with a 12 hour clock that the `tt` will be returned as part of the `ShortTimePattern`, but this solution just seams messy to me.

```
if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.IndexOf("tt") > -1)
  {
   TimeControl.clock24 = false;
  }
else
 {
  TimeControl.clock24 = true;
 }


/* This example produces the following output.
    CULTURE    PROPERTY VALUE
     en-US     h:mm tt
     ja-JP     H:mm
     fr-FR     HH:mm
*/
```

I am looking for a way of doing this that does not include scanning the Datetime Patters due to the fact that Datetime pattern can be changed by the user.

> The time pattern for a culture could contain anything (a user could
>   even create a custom culture where the ShortTimePattern is "\hello"
>   and then DateTime.ToString() would return "hello" for any time).

While `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator`  does work in some instances it does not work in all nor does testing for `H` vs `h`

Comment: _current PC is using a 24 hour clock or a 12 hour clock_ I don't think that's relevant with `ShortTimePattern` property. This is about culture settings, not pc is using ?12-hour_ or _24-hour_ format. This property just returns short time pattern of the `CurrentCulture` of your pc. It _may_ have time designator or not. Even if your `Currentculture` have `AMDesignator` or `PMDesignator` as a not empty string, this property _might_ not show them _at all_.

Comment: That is pretty much the same approach just using H instead of h

Comment: @SonerGönül tt returns the AM vs PM.   so assuming its there then we know its using a 12 hour clock. Do you have a better solution.  I am grasping at straws here.

Comment: You could also go for `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair that works and its nicer :)

Comment: It doesn't work for czech - `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-cs").DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator` will give you `dop.` even though the culture uses 24 hour clock by default. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Working on a WPF time picker which needs to be able to detect if the user is running a 24 hour clock or not so that it can either use AM PM and stop at 12 or use a 24 hour clock.